# Two balls stick together in a pool game?

Tags: physics, collision-detection

When multiple collisions occur between balls, sometimes they stick together. Mostly in cases of either of the balls having high velocity.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably something on the balls causing them to stick together. Try cleaning them with a soft cloth or wet paper towel.

Comment: Should be a comment, but still, hehe

Comment: yea mann...tried it with some napkin...bt dunno y it has started revolvin around wen i try to move it :)

Answer (score 1):

Can we see some physics code? How are you handling it? What do you mean by 'multiple collisions'? We're going to struggle helping without more detail.

Only reason I can think of is that the physics is treating it as a collision rather than an explosion (i.e. they stick together instead of flying apart).

EDIT: You could've said that in the original post. I also found this post on gamedev.net:

> wen multiple collision occurs between 2 or more balls..they tend to overlap...or sometimes rotate around themselves....cant figur out wy this is happening...

The problem is probably that your movement speeds mean the balls end up inside each other, and you do collision from there. A better option would be seeing if the objects intersect, and separating them before trying to move them.

Comment: stick together means they overlap...sometimes they get on top of one another and revolve like anythin...

Comment: hmm..actually its a carrom board game..nt pool...said that in the header..coz i thought ppl wudnt understand..dey've got same physics... 
is there some place were i can share my swf?

Comment: @Vishnu Ajit: Over here we like to use full sentences